# How to force to show beginning of the week in ssrs report

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012, ssrs-grouping

When the client select  `start date ,end date and group by` : weekly is there any way to force to show in the week column as first day of the week. For example if I choose `10/1/2019` as `start date` and `10/2/2019` as `end date` and `group by` : weekly then the week column should show `9/29/2019`
Right now the expression I am using is

`= Switch(Parameters!GroupbyTime=“4”, CDate(Fields!groupweek.value).ToString(“Mm/Dd/yyyy”)`

But it’s giving error can somebody help me ??

Comment: Please add error message in you question, and also tell us about the type of values hold by GroupByTime parameter and GroupByWeek field.

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract the number of the weekday from the date plus one day for the first day of the week.

```
=DATEADD("D", 1 - WEEKDAY(Parameters!START.Value), Parameters!START.Value)
```